# Exponential notation not plotting in seaborn or matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot a distribution plot of "Price" in Seaborn and it produces only one bar.

[image]

I can still perform arithmetic and descriptive statistics on the price. It just wont work with any visualisations. Is there a way to fix this?

I tried converting to data type to a float and integer with zero luck.

There are more than 800,000 records and no nulls. I expect at least some distribution.

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype('int64') - # Fail
```

[image]

```
sns.distplot(df["Price"])
df["Price"].mean()
```

273460.34639073786

The below gets a solid bar.

```
sns.distplot(df["Price"])
```

Comment: Oh I tried adding images of the output and the display of the exponential figures but my reputation is not good enough to add these

Comment: It still looks correct to me. The mean is inside the highest bar. Is there any evidence that the plot should look different, i.e. is the data not mostly close to the mean? Or is the maximum of the data much smaller than 3e7?

Comment: I uploaded the min,max,25th percentile and 75th percentile in the comment to the answer below as well as the .describe() function on the price. Does the displot seem normal given the actual values?

Comment: Try `sns.distplot(df["Price"], bins = 300, kde_kws=dict(gridsize=3000))` to get more resolution on you KDE curve.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. That helped. After also setting the xlim I got the desired result. You are a legend

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `bins` parameter in `displot`. This could reveal finer variations in the distribtion

```
sns.distplot(df["Price"], bins = 300)
```

Further you could try setting the y axis scale to log

```
ax = sns.distplot(df["Price"])
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

You could also set `norm_hist = False` to see exactly how many of these values are so similar

Comment: Thanks for getting back to this. I tried binning and setting the y_scale with not much success. I just want to view a decent representation of the distribution and I can't figure out how. Here are some links to images of the data and the results. Is there something I am missing? https://imgur.com/PD7QGho; https://imgur.com/qapLgMs; https://imgur.com/hUSiGhm; https://imgur.com/g2nJ5bB